# Рассчитать размер изображения в пикселях для Android

Tags: android, xml

1 вопрос: верно ли что в Android необходимо готовить изображения для максимально поддерживаемого разрешения (например xxxhdpi), а для всех меньших Android Studio с генерирует картинки с нужным разрешением?

2 вопрос: Необходимо нарисовать header. В xml разметке высота равна 96dp, ширина match_parent для android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.

- Какой ширины в пикселях должно быть изображение для (l-m-h-xh-xxh-xxxh)dpi?
- Какой высоты в пикселях должно быть изображение для (l-m-h-xh-xxh-xxxh)dpi при высоте изображения в 96dp?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

1. Не верно, сама студия генерацией уменьшенных изображений не занимается, однако можно найти плагины для импорта изображений с ресайзом их под все нужные плотности. Стоит так же заметить что наличие уменьшенных вариантов изображений для меньших плотностей не является обязательным, при загрузке изображения из ресурсов андройд сам отмасштабирует изображение под плотность устройства, однако это отнимает дополнительное время процессора и память при работе приложения, но зато немного экономит на размере apk. Так же на устройствах с малым объёмом памяти и малых плотностях может возникнуть OutOfMemory ошибка если будут большие изображения для намного большей плотности.
2. Про ldpi можно уже забыть, а для остальных пропорции такие:

   - mdpi: 1dp = 1px
   - hdpi: 1dp = 1.5px
   - xhdpi: 1dp = 2px
   - xxhdpi: 1dp = 3px
   - xxxhdpi: 1dp = 4px

Изображение для фона заголовка должно быть такой ширины какой вам надо. Если вам надо что оно всегда растягивалось на всю ширину то делаете [9patch](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/help/draw9patch.html) изображение указывая что должно растягиваться по горизонтали.

Comment: А что делать, если изображение растровое, т.е. тянуть его нельзя?

Comment: А что простите мешает тянуть растровые изображения? 9patch собственно для них и создан. Фон для чего то у чего нет конкретной фиксированной ширины и/или высоты в любом случае должен быть либо тянущимся либо повторяющимся.